# Where can I ask a question about where to find an old question?

Tags: discussion, support

This question might be a little [too META](https://xkcd.com/1447/).

I am trying to find a question posted to [META](/.) some time ago. It was extremely helpful, but I am now unable to find the question by searching for it.

<sub>*This particular question was a discussion on how to cast votes. Some were voting up poor questions simply because there were already many up-votes, and others were voting down good questions from new members. One answer provided a helpful diagram with green and red boxes that highlighted the title, question body, current question score, and the members who posed the question, with guidance on which boxes to look at when deciding how to vote.*</sub>

In general, when I cannot find a question using any of the following tools:

- Stack Exchange search
- Browser history
- List of suggested duplicate questions

where should I go to seek personal help about finding a particular question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should discuss the question you're looking for in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/).

If you think your request would be useful to latecomers, you can post a separate question. Try to write it as similar to the question you're finding as you can, but **use your own wordings**. Luckily enough it'll be closed as duplicate, but I think you're likely to get *similar* answers without having the question closed.

Since you can't find the original question with the methods you've given, there are likely latecomers who can't either. They may use similar wordings as you, which is the case a separate question can be helpful to them.